# Determine tetrad of local inertial frame numerically

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, computational-physics

Let $g_{\mu\nu}$ be a metric of a curved spacetime. However, we do not know its analytical form. We only know $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its derivatives from a former numerical simulation and the underlying coordinate frame, i.e. Cartesian, spherical or cylindrical.

I need the tetrad $e^\bar\mu_{\ \ \ \mu}$ which allows me to transform any tensor from the Eulerian frame to a local inertial system. My idea was to solve the equation

\begin{equation}
\eta_{\bar\mu\bar\nu} = e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}e^\nu_{\ \ \ \bar\nu} g_{\mu\nu} 
\end{equation}

where $\eta_{\bar\mu\bar\nu}$ is the flat metric of the local inertial frame in the same coordinate system as the metric in the Eulerian frame, i.e. Cartesian, spherical or cylindrical.

However, this system of equations has 16 unknows (the components of the tensor $e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}$) but only 10 equations. This is due to the above equation being invariant under Lorentz-transformations,

\begin{align}
\eta_{\bar\mu\bar\nu} &= e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}e^\nu_{\ \ \ \bar\nu} g_{\mu\nu}\\
\Lambda^{\bar\mu}_{\ \ \ \hat\mu}\Lambda^{\bar\nu}_{\ \ \ \hat\nu}\eta_{\bar\mu\bar\nu} &= \Lambda^{\bar\mu}_{\ \ \ \hat\mu}\Lambda^{\bar\nu}_{\ \ \ \hat\nu}e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}e^\nu_{\ \ \ \bar\nu} g_{\mu\nu}\\
\eta_{\hat\mu\hat\nu} &= b^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \hat\mu}b^{\nu}_{\ \ \ \hat\nu} g_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}

with $b^\mu_{\ \ \ \hat\mu} = \Lambda^{\bar\mu}_{\ \ \ \hat\mu}e^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}$. The Minkowski metric is invariant under Lorentz-transformations, thus the two metrics $\eta_{\bar\mu\bar\nu}$ and $\eta_{\hat\mu\hat\nu}$ are identical and both $e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu}$ and $b^{\mu}_{\ \ \ \hat\mu}$ are valid solutions.

Now I should be able to define the rotation and the boost of my inertial system and then solve for a unique tetrad. So far I was only able to narrow a few components down. Let $u^\mu$ be the four-velocity of the local inertial system, expressed in the Eulerian frame. The same vector in the inertial system then takes the form $u^{\bar\mu} = (u^{\bar0},u^{\bar\imath}) = (1,\vec0)$. This allows us to calculate the first column of our tetrad,

\begin{align}
u^\mu &= e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar\mu} u^{\bar\mu} = e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar0}.
\end{align}

This fixes the velocity of the inertial frame and should thus eliminate the free components related to the Lorentz-boosts. Even though the above equation looks like we are fixing 4 components of our 6 unkonws, we actually only fix the 3 boost components. This is due to the $0^{th}$ component of the four velocity being dependent on the other three thanks to the velocity normalization, $u_\mu u^\mu = -1$. This normalization is contained in our original tetrad equation if we look at the $00-$component,

\begin{equation}
-1 = \eta_{\bar0\bar0} = e^\mu_{\ \ \ \bar0}e^\nu_{\ \ \ \bar0} g_{\mu\nu}
= u^\mu u^\nu g_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

For the freedom of choice in the rotation of the tetrad I would like it to be aligned with the first spatial axis of the Eulerian frame and being right-handed orthogonal,

\begin{align}
e^a_{\ \ \ \bar a} e^b_{\ \ \ \bar b} \delta_{ab}=\delta_{\bar a\bar b}.
\end{align}

Any idea how to implement this in a solver?